# Makehuman modelling with py script?

Tags: python, modeling, makehuman

I used MakeHuman in a combination with Blender to model and animate a character and it works perfectly. The Problem now is, that I need a variaty on different human models. Tall, small, chubby, thin and so on. Since MH is open source and developed with python it should be possible to do the modelling automatic (random measurements) from a script. Is this possible? And how? I already found out that there should be a scripting tab in the MH GUI, but I think I need some additional tool therefore to enable it?!

Hope someone has done something like this, I could not find anything helpful in other forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scripting tab can be enabled under Settings->Plugins->7_scripting. When you restart MH, there should be a Scripting tab under Utilities. I have not yet run across any documentation, but the GUI does have some example API calls that you can append to your script by clicking the button. Good luck; I'm trying to figure out how to use it, too.